# Not receiving new entries from the Room table I observe

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using `Room` as a database layer in my application and I read this blog post [here](https://tkolbusz.github.io/controlling-database-flow/) which states :

`In your Room’s table Dao, return Flowable<List<SomeEntity>> that will stream data of specified Query each time database is updated.`

So what I did is opening shell (`adb shell`) and navigating to database folder and run `sqlite mydatabase.db` and inserting a new entry :

```
INSERT INTO notification VALUES(1, 101, "14", null, "name", "2007-11-11 20:20:20", null, 1, "1");
```

where `notification` is the table I'm observing like :

```
@Override
public Flowable<List<Notification>> getNotifications() {
    return dao.getNotificationsSorted();
}
```

from my `NotificationsRepository` but that didn't trigger an update so either I understand that quote above wrong or insert doesn't counts as an update.
Should I change `Flowable` with `LiveData` or add a `PublishSubject` or am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT : code from my repository class :

```
@Override
public Flowable<List<Notification>> loadData() {

    return localDataSource.getNotifications()
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread());
}
```

Comment: obviously it will update **only if you will use Room to insert/update/delete**

Comment: oh, now that I think of it again seems to me that you might be right! Thanks!